MOOC - Own_language exercise
I'm working on this assignment now and it seems to work with the tests MOOC provides. You can find the assignment here: https://programming-24.mooc.fi/part-7/6-more-features
The problem is that I get an error when I try to submit it, but I do not understand what is happening.
My code:
import string

def run(program: list):
    commands_list = format_commands(program)
    locations = {}
    for commands in commands_list:
        action = commands[0]
        if action[-1] == ":":
            locations[action[:-1]] = commands_list.index(commands)
    length_commands_list = len(commands_list)
    from_index = 0
    while from_index < length_commands_list:
        command = commands_list[from_index]
        action = command[0]
        length_command = len(command)
        if length_command == 6:
            variabel = command[1]
            comparison = command[2]
            variabel2 = command[3]
            action2 = command[4]
            location = command[5]
            if comparison == ">=":
                if variabel2.isdigit():
                    if variables[variabel] >= int(variabel2):
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
                elif variables[variabel] <= variables[variabel2]:
                    if action2 == "JUMP":
                        if command[-1] == "quit":
                            break
                        else:
                            from_index = locations[location]
            if comparison == "<=":
                if variabel2.isdigit():
                    if variables[variabel] <= int(variabel2):
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
                else: 
                    if variables[variabel] <= variables[variabel2]:
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
            if comparison == "==":
                if variabel2.isdigit():
                    if variables[variabel] == int(variabel2):
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
                else: 
                    if variables[variabel] == variables[variabel2]:
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
            if comparison == ">":
                if variabel2.isdigit():
                    if variables[variabel] > int(variabel2):
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
                else: 
                    if variables[variabel] > variables[variabel2]:
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
            if comparison == "<":
                if variabel2.isdigit():
                    if variables[variabel] < int(variabel2):
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
                else: 
                    if variables[variabel] < variables[variabel2]:
                        if action2 == "JUMP":
                            if command[-1] == "quit":
                                break
                            else:
                                from_index = locations[location]
            from_index += 1
        elif length_command == 3:
            variabel = command[1]
            value = command[2]
            if action == "MOV":
                assignment(variables, variabel, value)
            elif action == "ADD":
                add_value(variables, variabel, value)
            elif action == "SUB":
                sub_value(variables, variabel, value)
            elif action == "MUL":
                multiply_value(variables, variabel, value)
            from_index += 1
        elif length_command == 2:
            location = command[1]
            if action == "PRINT":
                result = print_result(command, variables)
            elif action == "JUMP":
                from_index = locations[location]
            from_index += 1
        elif length_command == 1:
            if action == "END":
                break
            from_index += 1
    return result


def format_commands(program: list):
    commands_list = []
    for command in program:
        command_list = command.split(" ")
        commands_list.append(command_list)
    return commands_list


def print_result(command: str, variables_dict: dict):
    variabel = command[1]
    if variabel in variables_dict:
        printed.append(variables_dict[variabel])
    else:
        printed.append(int(variabel))
    return printed


def assignment(variables_dict: dict, variabel: str, value: str):
    if value.isdigit():
        variables_dict[variabel] = int(value)
    else:
        variables_dict[variabel] = variables_dict[value]


def add_value(variables_dict: dict, variabel: str, value: str):
    if value.isdigit():
        variables_dict[variabel] += int(value)
    else:
        variables_dict[variabel] += variables_dict[value]


def sub_value(variables_dict: dict, variabel: str, value: str):
    if value.isdigit():
        variables_dict[variabel] -= int(value)
    else:
        variables_dict[variabel] -= variables_dict[value]


def multiply_value(variables_dict: dict, variabel: str, value: str):
    if value.isdigit():
        variables_dict[variabel] *= int(value)
    else:
        variables_dict[variabel] *= variables_dict[value]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    variables = {}
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        variables[letter] = 0
    
    printed = []

I expect to be able to deliver the above task, since all the tests work. But I get this error instead:

I've tried removing constants (I had constants before), running tests with the program they say is failing, etc.
Test code:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from tmc import points
from tmc.utils import load, load_module, reload_module, get_stdout, check_source
from functools import reduce
import os
import os.path
import textwrap
from random import choice, randint

exercise = 'src.own_language'
function = "run"

class OwnLanguageTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[AssertionError("Asking input from the user was not expected")]):
           cls.module = load_module(exercise, 'en')

    def test_0a_main_program_ok(self):
        ok, line = check_source(self.module)
        message = """The code for testng the functions should be placed inside
if __name__ == "__main__":
block. The following row should be moved:
"""
        self.assertTrue(ok, message+line)

    @points('7.own_programming_language-part1')
    def test1_function_exists(self):
        try:
            from src.own_language import run
        except:
            self.assertTrue(False, "Your program should contain function named as run")

    @points('7.own_programming_language-part1')
    def test2_no_loop(self):
        tests = []
        program1 = ["PRINT A","END"]
        result1 = [0]
        tests.append((program1,result1))
        program2 = ["MOV A 5","PRINT A"]
        result2 = [5]
        tests.append((program2,result2))
        program3 = ["MOV A 1","MOV B 1","ADD A B","ADD B A","ADD A B","ADD B A","PRINT A","PRINT B"]
        result3 = [5,8]
        tests.append((program3,result3))
        program4 = ["MOV A 2","MUL A A","MUL A A","MUL A A","MUL A A","PRINT A"]
        result4 = [65536]
        tests.append((program4,result4))
        program5 = ["MOV A 10","PRINT A","MOV B A","SUB B 8","PRINT B","SUB A B","PRINT A"]
        result5 = [10,2,8]
        tests.append((program5,result5))
        for test in tests:
            with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[AssertionError("Asking input from the user was not expected")]):
                reload_module(self.module)
                run = load(exercise, function, 'en')
                try:
                    result = run(test[0])
                except:
                    self.assertFalse(True, "Program "+str(test[0])+" caused an error")
                self.assertEqual(result, test[1], "Program "+str(test[0])+" returns an incorrect result "+str(result)+", the correct result would be "+str(test[1]))

    @points('7.own_programming_language-part2')
    def test3_all_commands(self):
        tests = []
        program1 = ["PRINT A","END"]
        result1 = [0]
        tests.append((program1,result1))
        program2 = []
        result2 = []
        tests.append((program2,result2))
        program3 = ["MOV A 10","start:","PRINT A","SUB A 1","IF A > 0 JUMP start","END"]
        result3 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
        tests.append((program3,result3))
        program4 = ["MOV A 1","MOV B 1","start:","MUL A 2","ADD B 1","IF B != 101 JUMP start","PRINT A"]
        result4 = [1267650600228229401496703205376]
        tests.append((program4,result4))
        program5 = ["MOV A 1","MOV B 999","start:","ADD A 1","SUB B 1","ADD C 1","IF A == B JUMP end","JUMP start","end:","PRINT C"]
        result5 = [499]
        tests.append((program5,result5))
        program6 = ["MOV N 100","PRINT 2","MOV A 3","start:","MOV B 2","MOV Z 0","test:","MOV C B","new:","IF C == A JUMP virhe","IF C > A JUMP pass_by","ADD C B","JUMP new","virhe:","MOV Z 1","JUMP pass_by2","pass_by:","ADD B 1","IF B < A JUMP test","pass_by2:","IF Z == 1 JUMP pass_by3","PRINT A","pass_by3:","ADD A 1","IF A <= N JUMP start"]
        result6 = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
        tests.append((program6,result6))
        for test in tests:
            with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[AssertionError("Asking input from the user was not expected")]):
                reload_module(self.module)
                run = load(exercise, function, 'en')
                try:
                    result = run(test[0])
                except:
                    self.assertFalse(True, "Program "+str(test[0])+" causes on error")
                self.assertEqual(result, test[1], "Program "+str(test[0])+" returns an incorrect result "+str(result)+", the correct result would be "+str(test[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


Fixed myself now. Looks like the problem was the function “print_result”. Have removed it and moved the code into the function “run”
